# Transpose of a matrix which has decimal values in its array

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix, transpose

This is the error: cannot convert 'double ( * )[3]' to 'int (*)[3] transpose(matrixA, matrixB); but the same code is working when I'm changing the data type to int. How can I fix my code?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define M 3
#define N 4

// This function stores transpose of A[][] in B[][]
void transpose(double A[][N], int B[][M])
{
    double i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            B[i][j] = A[j][i];
}

// This function prints the elements of the matrix.
void print(double matrix[][M])
{
    cout << "The resultant matrix is" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double matrixA[M][N] = {{1.3, 2, 3, 4.5},
                         {5, 6.6, 7.8, 8},
                         {4.7, 5, 3, 2.9}};

    double matrixB[N][M], i, j;

    transpose(matrixA, matrixB);
    print(matrixB);
    return 0;
}
```

Thank You

Comment: `void transpose(double A[][N], int B[][M])` Your second parameter should be `double`, should it not?

Comment: `for (double i = 0; i < N; i++)` Although your array contains doubles the indices are still integers. You should use int for your index variables as done in the other function.

Comment: why do you edit the whole code? that makes existing answers invalid

Comment: There are no decimals here. Decimal is a radix. Floating-point is used for *real numbers,* and the part after the decimal point is the fractional part. Please don't misuse standard terminology.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience guys I changed the whole code accidently, but now I've undone my mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, in `void transpose(double A[][N], int B[][M])` the type of `B` should be `double` , as it is declared in `main` : `double matrixB[N][M]`.

Secondly, while [using `double` as loop counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31723131/double-variable-as-loop-counter) isn't necessarily going to raise an error, accessing array requires indexes to be integers.

As @ivan.ukr mentioned:

> Standard C header file `stddef.h` (or `cstdddef` in C++) defines
> (typically, via `typedef`) special unsigned integer data type `size_t` (or
> `std::size_t` in C++) which should be normally used as size of memory
> are or array or memory / array index.

So your code now is :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define M 3
#define N 4

// This function stores transpose of A[][] in B[][]
void transpose(double A[][N], double B[][M])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < M; j++)
            B[i][j] = A[j][i];
}

// This function prints the elements of the matrix.
void print(double matrix[][M])
{
    cout << "The resultant matrix is" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
            cout << matrix[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    double matrixA[M][N] = {{1.3, 2, 3, 4.5},
                         {5, 6.6, 7.8, 8},
                         {4.7, 5, 3, 2.9}};

    double matrixB[N][M], i, j;

    transpose(matrixA, matrixB);
    print(matrixB);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
The resultant matrix is
1.3 5 4.7
2 6.6 5
3 7.8 3
4.5 8 2.9
```

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ you should normally use integer types for expressing array sizes ans indexes. Because memory addresses and as result, differences of memory addresses, and offsets from some starting address are all integer numbers, not floating point ones. That's why compiler gives you such an error, and `int` works but `double` does not. Furthermore, standard C header file `stddef.h` (or `cstdddef` in C++) defines (typically, via `typedef`) special unsigned integer data type `size_t` (or `std::size_t` in C++) which should be normally used as size of memory area or array or memory / array index. There is also another `typedef`ed type called `ptrdiff_t` (and `std::ptrdiff_t` in C++) which represent difference between two memory addresses, but `ptrdiff_t` is signed type and can be negative.